# how the characterCount was printed to 48?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Access3 {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                String[][] wordData = {{"study", "consider", "examine", "learn"}, {"ponder", "read", "think", "cogigate"}};
                
                int characterCount = 0;
                for(String[] stringRow : wordData) {
                    for(String s : stringRow) {
                        characterCount += s.length();
                   
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(characterCount);// how is the sum came out to 48????
                
                int i = 0, j = 0;
                while(i<wordData.length) {
                    j=0;
                    while(j<wordData[i].length) {
                        System.out.println(wordData[i][j] + ": [" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]");
                        j++;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: [It outputs 48, not 45](https://ideone.com/OJncA0) - which is just the length of strings in your arrays summed up.

Comment: yes I understood that the characterCount is arrays's sum but I don't understand how they was sum up to 48..?

Comment: 5+8+7+5+6+4+5+8 = 48.

Comment: By adding up the length of all words. eG `"study"` has a length of 5, `"consider"` has a length of 8, `"examine"` 7, `"learn"` 5 and so on. Add them al, together and you have 48.

Answer (score 2):

Per the question

```
String[][] wordData = {
 {"study", //      5
  "consider", //   8
  "examine", //    7
  "learn"}, //     5
 {"ponder", //     6
  "read", //       4
  "think", //      5
  "cogigate"}}; // 8
```

Simply addition at this point

```
5 + 8 + 7 + 5 + 6 + 4 + 5 + 8 = 48
```

Comment: got it ! thank you very much !